# Как узнать, успешен ли запрос к БД или нет?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Как узнать, успешен ли запрос к БД или нет?

```
 $res =  mysql_query("UPDATE center SET number = 2 WHERE id = 'Valera'");
```

$res будет равен 1, при успешном запросе и 0 при неудачном ???

Comment: Эммм... Я даже не знаю что ответить.
Наверное ответ - ДА.

Answer (score 9):

Только для запросов SELECT, SHOW, EXPLAIN, DESCRIBE, mysql_query() возвращает указатель на результат запроса, или FALSE если запрос не был выполнен. В остальных случаях, mysql_query() возвращает TRUE в случае успешного запроса и FALSE в случае ошибки. Значение не равное FALSE говорит о том, что запрос был выполнен успешно. Он не говорит о количестве затронутых или возвращённых рядов. Вполне возможна ситуация, когда успешный запрос не затронет ни одного ряда.

Answer (score 4):

Именно для update - можно использовать:

```
$res =  mysql_query("UPDATE center SET number = 2 WHERE id = 'Valera'");
if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) { // проапдейтилось 1 или больше строк
   // запрос успешен.
} else {
   // нечего обновлять.
}
```